# Why recursion occurs in reverse

Tags: javascript, recursion

The question is, does the function pause at the line where the function is called again or does it executes fully and then come back to that line (where the same function is called).

I also have this example which shows that recursion occurs in reverse (I guess each inner function keep reference to its outer function and execution occurs in reverse to normal order).

Please go in much details as possible.

```js
function func(n) {
  if(n > 0) func(n-1) 
  console.log(n)
}

func(10) // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

// while I was expecting 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Comment: Trace the code's execution on paper. Which happens first? The recursive call, or your print?

Comment: Switch the order of the `console.log` and `if` statements.  What @Dave said above.

Comment: recursive call will call the function again and again until n is = 0, then all console logs get triggered in reverse order because it's nested.

Comment: This has nothing to do with recursion, really. If you do `function func(n) { if (n > 0) { console.log(n-1); } console.log(n); }`, there is no recursion, but `func(10)` still prints `9, 10`, not `10, 9`.

Comment: Have a look here http://www.pythontutor.com/javascript.html#code=function%20func%28n%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%28n%20%3E%200%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20func%28n-1%29%20%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%28n%29%0A%7D%0A%0Afunc%2810%29%3B%20&curInstr=25&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D

Comment: i you want it in descending order print it before if condition as @TimBiegeleisen said

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's not the point. the point is, 'does it pause and keep going inside or does it console.log the value of n first'

Comment: @Syed.bcc It executes your code in the order it's written.

Comment: thank dane, but than I should see the order start from 10.

Comment: @Syed.bcc Why do you think so? Your log is *after* the recursive call. "In order" means... in order. You make a call. That call makes a call. That call makes a call, etc. *Then* it stops making calls, and what's next? The logging. As I said: play computer and execute the code on paper.

Comment: All function calls pauses further execution. Eg. If you have two `console.log` after each other it's not ambiguous i which order it will print. The second waits for the first to finish. Recursive functions are **nothing special**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your expected output, just print using `console.log` *before* making the recursive call:

```js
function func(n) {
    console.log(n)
    if(n > 0)
         func(n-1) 
}

func(10) // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Regarding your question about whether the recursive function "pauses", or keeps going, the answer is that when it makes another recursive call, it stops in its tracks until that call returns.  This is the reason why your current code is printing 1, 2, ..., 10.  This happens because each function call stops when making the recursive call, and only wakes up again after that call has completely finished.  This means that the smallest base case value gets printed first, then larger subsequent values get printed in reverse order.

Comment: that's what I wanted to hear. thanks for making it clear.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to use debugger tools in chrome to trace the codes execution. Recursion does happen backwards because it has to meet your base case in order to exit. Every time it does not meet your base case the current running function is put in call stack (in JS). In you case `func(n-1` gets called and previous `func` is put in call stack. Once your base case is met, your `func`s that are in call stack start to continue running (from leftover line -> `console.log`). Since the nature of stacks is Last In First Out (LIFO), you functions run in reverse.

Comment: so it's using Stacks DS to keep track of its outer function, right?

Comment: @Syed.bcc I don't know what "Stacks DS" is, but in general, there's a stack frame created for every function call, that it's recursive is irrelevant (unless there's trail call optimization going on, which can change things a bit, but there's still a stack frame).

Answer (score 3):

```js
function func(n) {
   console.log(n) //output 3 2 1
   if(n > 0)
      func(n-1) 

   console.log(n) //output 1 2 3
}

func(3) //Taking small digit for quick explanation
```

When `func(3)` is called from `main()`, memory is allocated to `func(3)` and a local variable `test` is initialized to `3` and statement 1 to 4 are pushed on the stack as shown in below diagram.

It first prints `3`. In statement 2, `func(2)` is called and memory is allocated to `func(2)` and a local variable `test` is initialized to `2` and statement 1 to 4 are pushed in the stack.

Similarly, `func(2)` calls `func(1)` and `func(1)` calls `func(0)`.

`func(0)` goes to `if` statement and it returns to func(1). Remaining statements of `func(1)` are executed and it returns to `func(2)` and so on.

In the output, value from 3 to 1 are printed and then 1 to 3 are printed. The memory stack has been shown in below diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function is not special in terms of calling it.

If you call a regular function then the function goes off, does its thing then returns.

```
function increase(i) 
{
    return i+1;
}

function caller()
{
    var n = 0;
    while(n<10)
    {
        n = increase(n);
        console.log(n);
    } 
}
```

So what will happen is that when you call `caller`, it will call `increase` which will do its job then return, then `caller` will call `console.log` and then the while loop will start again, until `n` is 10.

A recursive function does the same. The difference is that a recursive function calls itself.

```
function self_increase(i, target)
{
    console.log(i);
    if(i < target) 
    {
        return self_increase(i+1,target);
    }
    return i;
}
```

So in the recursive function you call the `console.log` first, because things happen in the order you write them down and if you put it after the call to the recursive function then you won't see the call to `console.log`, because you are returning the result of the function, which causes the function to exit. So every call to the recursive function is starting a new function call, like a normal function, and progress cannot continue until the function returns, and because the function calls itself you need to have an exit condition for the function, otherwise it will loop forever, much like if you write `while(true)...`.